# How to prevent component overlay ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic project and seem to be stuck on something. 
I am designing an expandable component which listens for `ionScroll` events and adjusts the size of the header bar. The header bar is working alright but whenever it is supposed to disappear it leaves a sort of container that overlays the components of my `ionContent`.

[image: This image]

The above image shows the overlay on the left when the component is not supposed to show and on the right we can see the component when it is supposed to show.
Here is my css code

```css
expandable {
    display: flex;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: block;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you upload your current code (the parts that are relevant to this issue to stackblitz.com. Its super hard to help you without actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. To prevent that overlay use

```
this.contentArea.resize();
```

This function resizes the area your content occupies